# Just using mysql real escape string

Tags: php, mysql

need guidance on how this mysql real escape string works on this statement, i don't want mysqli and the pdo types. i have tried it, but it is not working, need some help about this

```
$UserName =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UserName']);
$password =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);

            // Insert data into mysql 
            $sql1="INSERT INTO UserDetail (UserName,Password,Email_Address,Verifycode,AcoountStatus)VALUES('$UserName','$encry_pass','$email','$verify_code','Inactive')";
```

Comment: You *have* to use MySQLi or PDO... MySQL_* function are deprecated and being removed from usage.

Comment: If you want or not, mysql_* functions are deprecated in newer php versions...

Comment: You have are trying to interpolate 4 variables into your SQL and have only defined two of them in the code you've shared. You also haven't told us what you mean by "not working". This just assigns values to some variables - there shouldn't be any noticeable effect in the portion of code you've shared.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: _"I have tried it, but it is not working"_ <-- well, try harder. Read the docs, find some tuts and how-to's, because there is no alternative.  `mysql_*` is deprecated, and will be removed from PHP, `PDO` and `mysqli_*` are its replacements. That's just the way it is

Comment: the strings like />., still can be enter in the sql database

Comment: "It is not working" does not really help a lot. You should share with us how it doest not work and what error messages you get, if any. You should also include more code, at least the part where you actually execute the query. Here you merely make a string with the INSERT-statement, not execute it.  

And you really DO want to use mysqli or the PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is not working … the strings like `/>`., still can be enter in the sql database

It is working.

`mysql_real_escape_string` is a function that **escapes** characters which have *special meaning in SQL*.

`/` and `>` do not have special meaning in SQL, so it shouldn't touch them.

If they did have special meaning, then the point of the function is to allow them to be inserted into the database. It makes changes such as converting `'` (meaning "Start or end an SQL string") to `\'` (meaning "An apostrophe").